How to make Final Cut use video's original colors?
I'm a new user of Final Cut Pro for iPad. I had some stuff I wanted to cut out of a video and did that successfully, but the exported result has a strong yellow cast and seems way overexposed.
The original video looks good, the project looks good on the timeline, and yet the end result is abysmal!
How can I tell Final Cut Pro for iPad to use the original video's color gamut/contrast/exposure or whatever so that what I export will look the same as the original?
